# Replace special characters in query statement?

Tags: string, postgresql, replace, substring

What `method` can I use to strip out all special characters and spaces in a string and replace with underscores in a query?

For example I would like to catch the following case where `table.field_val` = 'ex am.pl/e':

```
WHERE method(table.field_val) = 'ex_am_pl_e'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`translate()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html), e.g.:

```
select translate('ex am.pl/e', ' ./', '___');

 translate  
------------
 ex_am_pl_e
(1 row)
```

Comment: Best reason to use translate over regexp_replace?

Comment: It's much faster. Important for a larger dataset.

Comment: I can't seem to get translate to work for multiple characters, only one. i.e. `/' works but ' ./' doesn't? EDIT: I just realized the characters correspond to one another such that translate('string','123','abc');

Comment: You need as many underscores in the third string as different characters in the second string.

Answer (score 2):

regexp_replace:

```
t=# select regexp_replace( 'ex am.pl/e'::text,'[^0-9a-zA-Z]','_','g');
 regexp_replace
----------------
 ex_am_pl_e
(1 row)
```

or same shorter:

```
t=# select regexp_replace( 'ex am.pl/e'::text,'[^\w]','_','g');
 regexp_replace
----------------
 ex_am_pl_e
(1 row)
```

Comment: `[^\w]` is shorter

Comment: @Abelisto But `[^0-9a-zA-Z]` and `[^\w]` aren't quite the same thing. Sure, the replacement character is `_` but...

Comment: the list of "special characters" provided by op was space, dot, backslash - my answer is a wild guess anyway

Comment: @muistooshort Surely, but there is also no definition of "special characters".